# how to display the plotting pie chart into excel file beside the create table using dataframe and python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I have a python script that predict sentiment analysis for a dataframe  positive and negative sentiment  by adding a new field to the existing table. And i plot a pie chart of the  percentage of the positive and negative sentiment. At the end it saves the result to an excel file.

I want to add this plotting the pie chart beside the table  .

how to do this task?

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    test_twtr = pd.read_excel("F:/AIenv/sentiment_analysis/20200717_100219_Sentiment - Copy.xlsx",names=col_names)
    
    test_twtr['processed_TEXT'] = test_twtr['TRANSLATION'].apply(processTweet)
    test_twtr_preds = LR_Model.predict(test_twtr['processed_TEXT'])
    def_test_twtr_preds = test_twtr.copy()
    positives = def_test_twtr_preds["predictions"][def_test_twtr_preds.predictions ==1]
    negatives = def_test_twtr_preds["predictions"][def_test_twtr_preds.predictions ==0]
    
    slices_tweets = [format(100*len(positives)/len(def_test_twtr_preds["predictions"])), format(100*len(negatives)/len(def_test_twtr_preds["predictions"]))]
    analysis = ['pos', 'neg']
    colors = ['yellow', 'red']
    plt.pie(slices_tweets, labels=analysis, startangle=90, autopct='%.1f%%',colors = colors)
    plt.title("Percentage of sentiment analysis")
    plt.show()
    
    df_test_tweet_preds_to_csv = def_test_twtr_preds.to_csv(outputPath, index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly insert an matplot image to an Excel file using Pandas.
You can do a little Workaround:

1. save the image
2. export the data to excel
3. open the excel file with xlsxwriter
4. and load the Image to the Excel file. and save it again

for information about how to insert an image to excel see:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html

Comment: If the user wants to create a pie chart then the chart APIs in XlsxWriter may be a better option: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_pie.html